# mysql multiple unique keys with on duplicate key reference

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have a table structure like this

```
id,f1,f2,f3,f4
```

id is primary key , f1 and f3 are unique keys

my question is when i use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Which key is it considering for valuation

consider the query

```
INSERT INTO t1 (f1,f2,f4) VALUES (.....) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE f4=...."
```

As shown above will it consider the key to be f1 ? or f3 or the id

and if i have a query like this

```
INSERT INTO t1 (f1,f2,f3,f4) VALUES (.....) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE f4=...."
```

what key will it consider then ?

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), emphasis mine:

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value **in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY**, an
>   UPDATE of the old row is performed.

An insert attempt that would cause a duplicate for any unique constraint on the table would cause the alternative action to be triggered. Note that it is advised (in general) not to use the ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax with tables that contain multiple unique indexes:

> In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.

Comment: Well any violation will trigger the alternate action, so priority wouldn't have much meaning. That said, direct answer is afaik, no.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for what to do if a table has multiple unique indexes and you would like to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (only on one of the keys)?

Comment: Are those multiple unique indexes or one composite unique index? As per the manual, this clause must be avoided for multiple unique indexes since it may lead to inconsistent data. However, you can use it with a composite unique key without any problem.